# Creating date object in the future in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a skiing app in react, where I want to set some dates, for when a skiing event occurs. Whenever I use the date object, and pass in a date that is in the future into the constructor, it just displays

```js
Nan/Nan/Nan
```

Here is my code:

```js
<SkiDayList
  days={[
    {
      resorts: "Squaw Valley",
      date: new Date("20/8/2018"),
      powder: true,
      backcountry: false
    },
    {
      resorts: "Val Thorens",
      date: new Date("5/10/2018"),
      powder: true,
      backcountry: true
    },
    {
      resorts: "Val Desire",
      date: new Date("5/10/2018"),
      powder: false,
      backcountry: true
    },
    {
      resorts: "Squaw Valley",
      date: new Date("1/2/2018"),
      powder: true,
      backcountry: false
    }
  ]}
/>
```

I know I could just multiply the dates or add values, but is it best practice to do that inside the constructor, or is it better to create values outside the component, and then pass them in, I'm new to react, some I'm not sure, what is the best practice.

EDIT:

here is my SkiDayRow.js component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FaBeer } from "react-icons/fa";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FaBeer } from "react-icons/fa";

export const SkiDayRow = ({ resort, date, powder, backcountry }) => (
  <tr>
    <td>
      {date.getMonth() + 1}/{date.getDate()}/{date.getFullYear()}
    </td>
    <td>{resort}</td>
    <td>{powder ? <FaBeer /> : null}</td>
    <td>{backcountry ? <FaBeer /> : null}</td>
  </tr>
);
```

Comment: It's difficult to say why you get `Nan/Nan/Nan` without seeing how your `SkiDayList` component is implemented.

Comment: I apologize, i will make an edit

Comment: `SkiDayList` doesn't contain enough information either, sadly. You must show us the code where you are using the date objects. Maybe `SkiDayRow` is the one?

Comment: Yes it was the wrong component, it is edited now

Comment: I found out that it displays the NaN whenver i have a date, over 12

Comment: What do you mean by "over 12"? Does the `x` in `5/x/2018` sometimes go over 12 in your code? That would be an invalid date, so that is probably why you get the error.

Comment: Yes, I realize that know... Thank you for clearing that up for me, i forgot all about the fact, that the getMonth method works  a zero-based array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That object would be so basic that I'm not sure it needs to be a React component. You could use the browser with [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) to format a date.

If you still want a component you could do something like this.

**Date Component:**

```
export class DateComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const {day, month, year} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>{month}/{day}/{year}</div>
    ):
  }
}
```

And to **use it** just pass the props to the component:

```
(...)
render() {
  return (
    <DateComponent day={10} month={08} year={2018} />
  );
}
```

**Edit**: Added snippet with `DateTimeFormat`

```js
const today = Date.now();

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit'}).format(today));
```

Comment: I see your point, but in order to keep more structure to my project, i think it would be best, to pass a date attribute into the object?

Comment: If you want to add more functionality to the date component such as more format types, support for other time zones, maybe fonts, colors or other ways to display the date, etc it would make sense to build a component. If it's just plain date as a string I don't think you need it.